# Setting focus to a DataGridView row

Tags: c#, datagridview

The following source code is intended to set focus to the immediately previous row of a deleted row.

[image]

Suppose I want to delete an unwanted word `dddddddd` from the database. When I press the `Delete` button, I want the word `cynosure` to be focused and placed at the top of the `DataGridView` which is not the case right now.

[image]

Right now, it is displayed at the bottom.

[image]

**Source Code**

```
    void SetFocusToWord(Word concernedWord)
    {
        if (concernedWord != null)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                Word item = r.Tag as Word;

                if (concernedWord.Name == item.Name)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Focus();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0];

                    break;
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    } 

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int selectionIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
                    {
                        Word c = r.Tag as Word;

                        if (c != null)
                        {
                            _wordDatabase.Delete(c);
                        }
                    }

                    LoadToDataGridView();

                    if(selectionIndex > 0)
                    {
                        selectionIndex = selectionIndex - 1;
                    }

                    Word item = dataGridView1.Rows[selectionIndex].Tag as Word;

                    SetFocusToWord(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(SelectionErrorMessages.GetErrorMessageFor(typeof(Word)));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        } 

    void LoadToDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        List<Word> items = (List<Word>)_wordDatabase.Get();

        if (items != null)
        {
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (Word c in items)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(c.Name, c.Hint);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Tag = c;
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the database seems like an unnecessary step.

Based on how you want the grid to behave, try using code like this:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0) {
  int selectIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(selectIndex);
  if (selectIndex > 0) {
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    dataGridView1.Rows[selectIndex - 1].Selected = true;
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = selectIndex - 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Poor performance and abundance of unnecessary code in your project are the result of you not using winforms binding properly. I suggest you start utilizing control's [BindingContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bindingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and BindingSource accordingly. This should solve most of your problems.

For further details on winforms binding I recommend this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding).